Parsing slack command arguments
I wonder if there is some "standardized" slack commands format, so there are already some tools/strategies to parse slack commands, particularly "optional" args.
For example slack/github integration has this command:
/github subscribe org/repo workflows:{event:"pull_request","push" branch:"main","dev" actor:"ashokirla"}

Positional arguments are straightforward. But github uses this workflows argument more like optional one. So not sure if this format is invention by github or its standardized?
It looks somewhat like JSON, but not quite. Should I just use regex to parse this kind of arg or there are some better/simpler ways?
